# Why does this certain text on my website load differently from the rest of the page?

Tags: html, css, web

Link to website: https://brianle.blog/

If you try to refresh or navigate between pages, you'll notice "Brian Le" in the top left corner loads differently from the rest of the page.

Why is this?

Here you can take a look at my code: https://github.com/brianle8330/personal-website/

Comment: This might be of assistance [MCVE]

Comment: It uses a font that is missing. The browser waits till the request for the font fails before showing a replacement thus it shows up a bit later. Fix your fonts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bold font isn't loading properly. Try fixing that first:

[image: Font network requests]